# Import Modules vice versa

Tags: python, micropython

In **MicroPython** I created two modules 'mod_a' and 'mod_b'.
I am trying to grab functionality from one to the other and the other way around.

```
|mod_a
|  | foo.py
|  | __init__.py
|mod b
|  | baa.py
|  | __init__.py
```

***foo.py***

```
# necessary to grab module mod_b
import sys
sys.path.append('.')

from mod_b import Baa

class Foo:
    b = Baa()
    b.printer()
    
    def drinker(self):
        print('Drinking')
```

***baa.py***

```
import sys

# not working
# from mod_a import Foo

class Baa:
    
    def printer(self):
        print('Printer')
        print('b.Baa', sys.path)  => ['.' ...]

        # ==> how to get this working
        # a = Foo()
        # a.drinker()
```

So far I tried

```
import sys
import os

if '/' not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
    sys.path.insert(1, '.')
    sys.path.insert(2, '/mod_b')
    sys.path.insert(2, '/mod_a')
    sys.path.insert(2, '.mod_b')
    sys.path.insert(2, '.mod_a')
```

and

```
sys.modules.get('.mod_b')
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the following code **only** solves the import problem.
The code still has a **circular import** problem.

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Baa' from partially initialized
> module 'mod_b.baa' (most likely due to a circular import)
> (C:\Users\Guest\test\.\mod_b\baa.py)

When initializing class Foo, it needs to call Baa.printer() which calls a = Foo() need the uninitialized class Foo, you need to fix that later.

**foo.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'.')
from mod_b.baa import Baa

class Foo:
    b = Baa()
    b.printer()
    
    def drinker(self):
        print('Drinking')
```

**baa.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'.')
from mod_a.foo import Foo

class Baa:
    def printer(self):
        print('Printer')
        a = Foo()
        a.drinker()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it and it does not work (most likely due to the circular requirements). Besides that, I would still use `if '.' not in sys.path:` to ensure to not pollute the sys.path

Comment: Could you enhance your answer by pressing the statement of circular reference. Probably adding a source (link) to that. It seems this was my problem, why I checked your answer as best answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Circular imports are **not supported** in MicroPython up to v1.18.
MicroPython is largely based on Python 3.4 and [differences to Python 3.5 are documented](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/differences/python_35.html?highlight=circular%20imports) including circular imports.